# How to get a date range prompt using a SQL connection in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, odbc

So I have created a connection in MS Query and am now using it in Excel. I want to create a macro button that when I click it the query automatically runs.

However when it runs I want you to be allowed to select the input for some fields. For example the two date fields and the entry field here:

```
WHERE 
    (ENTERED_ON BETWEEN {ts '2020-02-01 00:00:00'} AND {ts '2020-02-14 00:00:00'}) 
    AND (ENTRY = 'apple')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also just to note the date and time has to be specifically in that format. I also want to keep the prompt as simple as possible for users so ideally with something like:

```
Dim sUserInput As String 
sUserInput = InputBox("Enter Number:", "Collect User Input")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an input prompt, I use a cell range to refer to my date range (which is much easier to format in the way you want it) and VBA coding that updates the command text of the SQL query within the excel workbook. So something like this:

```
Sql = Sql & " .... SELECT... FROM... " & vbCrLf 'enter your FROM and SELECT statements 
Sql = Sql & "WHERE " & vbCrLf
Sql = Sql & "ENTERED_ON BETWEEN '" & Range("A1") & "' AND '" & Range("A2") & "' " & vbCrLf 
Sql = Sql & "AND (ENTRY = 'apple')"

With ThisWorkbook.Connections("Your Connection Name Here").ODBCConnection
    .CommandText = Sql
    .Refresh
End With
```

You can then attach the command to a macro button which will update your command text string with your date ranges. For bigger queries, I would suggest using a SQL to VBA string online convert like here: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Saves alot of time!

Comment: Thanks a million for that! I eventually found that I can edit the parameters in Excel and have them as choice parameters pulling from a specific cell. I then linked this to a macro.